# Is there a need to check whether the jQuery library has loaded?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have been used jQuery many times but I just realized that though I have not done anything to wait or check for the jQuery plugin to be loaded, running jQuery code has not met problems.  My typical code is:

```
<html>
 ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 ...
<body>
  ...
</body>
<script>
  //jQuery code, eg:
  $('#xxx').load('yyyy.html'); 
  ... // more code
</script>
</html>
```

Then recently, I experienced the file from codeorigin.jquery.com failing sometimes or taking about 20s to load.  When using Chrome, I noticed that Chrome does not render the html page nor execute the JavaScript code in it until the loading activity of the referenced external script file is complete (could be a success or a failure).  This is excellent.

My question: is it a standard browser specification that browsers will always wait for the loading of all external scripts referenced in a page to complete before rendering and executing the html page?  Or does the browser merely execute the page sequentially, waiting for each  to complete before moving to the next line, and not asynchronously?  Or there is no defined order and it is the responsibility of web designers to ensure all external scripts are ready before using them?

Comment: The loading is not async. If you place scripts in the header they will be loaded and executed before reaching the the body.

Comment: agree, move your script tag to the bottom of the body. The script will be evaluated before you run anything listed after it, unless you add an async or defer attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you were just lucky that it worked! Probably your browser cached the file and so it was readily available. Yes! There is a need to check. I've run into issues where the library or resource is not available, for example with Google Maps. And there is no guarantee what a browser will do. When it sees the inline script, it will execute it immediately. Think of `<script>document.write("hello")</script>`. Browsers will fetch multiple resources asynchronously to speed up the download.

That said, the best practice is to use `<body onload="initialize();">` to start running scripts after the entire document is loaded. If you have a self contained script in a separate JS file, you can be sure it won't run until loaded. I've been doing Coffeescript recently, and the scripts are in separate files, and they attach a handler to `<body>` so it only runs when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#comments").on "click", ".aComment", ->
```